# Displaying real-time CSV data in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: csv, openlayers

is there a good way to display real-time csv data with OpenLayers 3?

http://geofon.gfz-potsdam.de/eqinfo/list.php?datemin=&datemax=&latmin=&latmax=&lonmin=&lonmax=&magmin=&fmt=html&nmax=10&fmt=csv

ol2 had the opportunity to display csv data, but how do i do that in ol3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a csv parser implemented yet but if not you could parse the csv yourself to geojson, for example with php... or you could test   http://mapbox.github.io/csv2geojson/
https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson

If it doesn't have to be csv then just get the layer in kml :
http://geofon.gfz-potsdam.de/eqinfo/list.php?latmin=&latmax=&lonmin=&lonmax=&magmin=&fmt=kml

http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/kml.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Solved the problem with ogr2ogr and a cronjob